# Text as place holder for textbox input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I notice that at some websites like http://academia.edu/, the signup form has some "place-holder" in their text input field. Such that in a textbox, there's no label but a rather slight font "First name" word inside the text box.

When using Firebug to investigate, I see the following code:

```
<input class="standard_text magic-default magic-default-on" id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" value="First Name">
```

It looks like there's some "magic" javascript happen behind the scene. But since I'm not familiar with javascript debugging yet, I can't trace out how they do that yet.

Does anyone know how to produce that effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For modern browsers you can use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute.

This will achieve the result you're after without any Javascript and will scale (won't do anything) in older browsers.

```
<input placeholder="First Name">
```

To get this working in older browsers you can include a little bit of jQuery:

```
$('input:text').focus(function(){
    if ( $( this ).val () === $( this ).attr ( 'placeholder' ) ) { 
      $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
    }
}
);
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZP9z3/3/)

Comment: I've added a `if` so that the code won't reset the value if user already entered something.

Comment: Where was the if put in the statement? It would be helpful to update code so future users know exactly what is being talked about. :)

Comment: @jlg clicking on the date of the edit will highlight the code that changed for you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a "onFocus" event handler for the input box, and clear the value of said input box. Off course you only clear the value if it's the default value ("First Name" in your example), so that you don't clear away whatever user entered if he returns to the input later.

You could also attach a "onBlur" event handler, and restore the value of the input box back to the default value (if user didn't enter anything).

Comment: well said. here's blueprints: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200710/autopopulating_text_input_fields_with_javascript/

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" size="30" type="text" value="First Name" onFocus="inputFocus('First Name', this)" onBlur="inputBlur('First Name', this)">
<script type="text/javascriptt">
  function inputFocus(ph, el){
    if(el.value == ph)
      el.value = "";
  }
  function inputBlur(ph, el){
    if(el.value == "")
      el.value = ph;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 placeholder is what you're looking for:

http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html

In your case it would be:

```
<input name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
```

But also you can do it 100% with javascript:

http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/experiments/forms/input-placeholder-text/